# In the proof of the eigenvalue problem regarding the elliptic operators in Evans's PDE book

Tags: partial-differential-equations

This question bases on Chapter 6 in Evans's *Partial Differential Equations*. To make the question self-contained, I would like to introduce some related definitions. Anyone familiar with Evans's book can jump directly to the question. (All I want to ask in this post is the very *first* step in the proof of a theorem.)

Consider the elliptic operator and its corresponding bilinear form

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

First of all we have energy estimates

> [image]

Now, my question is about the very first step in the proof of the following theorem

> [image]

The proof begins with this:

> [image]

The main part of the proof reduces (i) to the following:

> [image] 
>   where $K$ is some compact operator.

Finally, the proof draws the conclusion:

> [image]

### Here are my **questions**:

- At the beginning of the proof, an extra assumption of $\lambda$ is made: $\lambda>-\gamma$. How does one handle the other part: $\lambda\leq-\gamma$?
- Also at the beginning of the proof, the proof assumes that $\gamma>0$. How does one deal with the case $\gamma=0$?

---

Here is the whole proof of the theorem 5 for your reference:

> [image]

Comment: If $\lambda\le -\gamma$ and $Lu=\lambda u$, then from ineq. (ii) in theorem 2 you have $u=0$. If $\gamma=0$ then in ineq. (ii) of theorem 2 you have $\beta ||u||^2\le B[u,u]\le B[u,u]+||u||^2$, then you can replace $\gamma$ by 1 or whatever other positive number you want.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. What norm do you use for $\|\cdot\|$? Would you elaborate the $\gamma=0$ case?

Comment: Your comment is pretty much what I'm looking for. May I suggest you write it into an answer?

Comment: Dear Jack, I'm using the inequality $\beta||u||_{H^{1}_0}^2\le B[u,u]+\gamma ||u||_{L^2}^2$, since $Lu=\lambda u$, by the definition of weak solution $B[u,u]=\lambda||u||^2_{L^2}$. If $\gamma=0$ in Theorem 4, you can replace $B_{0}[u,v]$ by $B_{\gamma}[u,v]$ for $\gamma>0$, that's what you need to prove the properties of $K$. Excuse me by my delayed reply.